# GPU Render Greyed Out Since nVidia Driver Update

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

Longshot, but thought I'd ask incase anyone else has seen this. I updated the drivers for my RTX 3090 and "GPU Render" is greyed out. If I go into preferences > system and uncheck & recheck it, it works again, but I have to do that every time I launch Blender. Weird. Anyone else seen this?

Comment: Are you sure the preferences have been saved?

Comment: I am sure. The driver update messed with my 3D printer software too. Seems like an Nvidia thing.